# How to automatically start docker container on windows boot ~ Wait for docker to be running

Tags: windows, docker, batch-file, boot, autostart

I have a container that I pretty much need every time when starting my development PC, so I am trying to get it to autostart.

I have already written a .bat file that works fine for starting the container once docker is up, and have put that into the autostart folder on windows but...

...when starting my PC, that .bat executes before docker has started running, and thus terminates without starting the container. Once docker is up and running, I can use the .bat manually to start it just fine.

So here's my question: Is there anything I can add to my .bat to tell it to wait for docker to be running before trying to start the container?

Currently, the bat simply says `docker-compose up` and nothing else.

Comment: What do you mean by docker up?  And what do you mean by waiting docker to be running?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add

```
restart: unless-stopped
```

or

```
restart: always
```

to the container in your `docker-compose.yml`, then use `docker-compose up` manually once more. This will make Docker to start the container after Docker itself is started.

Comment: This still waits for windows login, doesn't work on boot

Comment: @TamasHegedus sorry for the confusion, I've edited the last line. Starting Docker before login is not what was asked in this question, but here is a relevant one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51252181/how-to-start-docker-daemon-windows-service-at-startup-without-the-need-to-log