# Auto Start Docker on Windows reboot

Tags: windows, docker, docker-for-windows

I created a task to autostart docker on windows server using TaskScheduler
referred to https://stackoverflow.com/a/59467740/12768108

1. As admin created a local "task-executor" user and added it to the administrator group.
2. As admin added the same user to the docker-users group

Now after logging into the system using another user account(already in the docker users group), I run the task manually from the task scheduler the docker services started with daemon mode and I am able to run all docker commands like "docker ps".

But when restarting the machine it only started two services of docker ie "docker desktop" and "docker desktop backend" and not others, also when tried to run docker ps gives below error

`error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running.: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/containers/json": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.`

I have also tried https://github.com/tfenster/dockeraccesshelper but this helps me achieve only point 1 of the description.

> Can someone please let me know what i am missing here ?